# Const Array Size in Struct

Tags: c#, arrays, constants

I need to be able to do the following:

```
public struct entry_h
{
    public ulong fileid;
    public byte hash[20];
};
```

Like in C/C++

I'm doing an unsafe pointer cast to a struct, that's why I need to be able to do this. :/

```
entries[i].ehash = *(entry_h*)(src + header_size + (R64(pup->entryCount) * 0x20) + (i * 0x20));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the unsafe keyword in C#, structs support fixed size buffers via the fixed keyword.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Example:

```
public fixed byte hash[20];
```

Otherwise, through safe code, it would be like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
public byte[] hash;
```